# Debian unstable repository and *t64 packages

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, deb

Why is Debian renaming some unstable packages from `orig_name` to `orig_namet64`? Some other questions:

- Where can I find the Official Policy for Debian Unstable?
- Where can I find out what is going on with the Debian user community as a whole?

Recent renamings:

```
$ dpkg -l "*t64" |head -n 50
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                Version                     Architecture Description
+++-===================================-===========================-============-=======================================================================
ii  libabsl20220623t64:amd64            20220623.1-3.1              amd64        extensions to the C++ standard library
ii  libappimage1.0abi1t64:amd64         1.0.4-5-3.1                 amd64        Core library for appimage
ii  libapr1t64:amd64                    1.7.2-3.2                   amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Library
ii  libaprutil1t64:amd64                1.6.3-2                     amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library
ii  libapt-pkg6.0t64:amd64              2.7.13+b1                   amd64        package management runtime library
ii  libarchive13t64:amd64               3.7.2-1.1                   amd64        Multi-format archive and compression library (shared library)
ii  libaribb24-0t64:amd64               1.0.3-2.1+b1                amd64        library for ARIB STD-B24 decoding (runtime files)
ii  libasound2t64:amd64                 1.2.11-1+b1                 amd64        shared library for ALSA applications
ii  libatk-bridge2.0-0t64:amd64         2.51.90-4                   amd64        AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge - shared library
ii  libatk1.0-0t64:amd64                2.51.90-4                   amd64        ATK accessibility toolkit
ii  libatopology2t64:amd64              1.2.11-1+b1                 amd64        shared library for handling ALSA topology definitions
ii  libatspi2.0-0t64:amd64              2.51.90-4                   amd64        Assistive Technology Service Provider Interface - shared library
ii  libboost-chrono1.83.0t64:amd64      1.83.0-2.1                  amd64        C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks
ii  libburn4t64:amd64                   1.5.6-1.1                   amd64        library to provide CD/DVD/BD writing functions
ii  libcamel-1.2-64t64:amd64            3.50.3-2.2                  amd64        Evolution MIME message handling library
ii  libcanberra-gtk3-0t64:amd64         0.30-12.2                   amd64        GTK+ 3.0 helper for playing widget event sounds with libcanberra
ii  libcanberra0t64:amd64               0.30-12.2                   amd64        simple abstract interface for playing event sounds
ii  libcdio-cdda2t64:amd64              10.2+2.0.1-1.1              amd64        library to read and control digital audio CDs
ii  libcdio-paranoia2t64:amd64          10.2+2.0.1-1.1              amd64        library to read digital audio CDs with error correction
ii  libcdio19t64:amd64                  2.1.0-4.1                   amd64        library to read and control CD-ROM
ii  libcfitsio10t64:amd64               4.3.1-1.1+b1                amd64        shared library for I/O with FITS format data files
ii  libclang1-15t64                     1:15.0.7-14                 amd64        C interface to the Clang library
ii  libclang1-16t64                     1:16.0.6-23                 amd64        C interface to the Clang library
ii  libclucene-contribs1t64:amd64       2.3.3.4+dfsg-1.2            amd64        language specific text analyzers (runtime)
ii  libclucene-core1t64:amd64           2.3.3.4+dfsg-1.2            amd64        core library for full-featured text search engine (runtime)
ii  libcmis-0.6-6t64                    0.6.2-2.1+b1                amd64        CMIS protocol client library
ii  libcolord-gtk4-1t64:amd64           0.3.1-1                     amd64        GTK4 convenience library for interacting with colord
ii  libcom-err2t64:amd64                1.47.0-2.3+b1               amd64        common error description library
ii  libcrypto++8t64:amd64               8.9.0-1.1                   amd64        General purpose cryptographic library - shared library
ii  libcups2t64:amd64                   2.4.7-1.2+b1                amd64        Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Core library
ii  libcupsfilters1t64:amd64            1.28.17-3.1+b1              amd64        OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Shared library
ii  libcurl4t64:amd64                   8.6.0-4                     amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
ii  libdb5.3t64:amd64                   5.3.28+dfsg2-6              amd64        Berkeley v5.3 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdirectfb-1.7-7t64:amd64          1.7.7-13                    amd64        direct frame buffer graphics (shared libraries)
ii  libdmapsharing-4.0-3t64:amd64       3.9.13-2                    amd64        DMAP client and server library - runtime
ii  libdmtx0t64:amd64                   0.7.7-1.2                   amd64        Data Matrix barcodes (runtime library)
ii  libdv4t64:amd64                     1.0.0-17.1                  amd64        software library for DV format digital video (runtime lib)
ii  libdvdread8t64:amd64                6.1.3-1.1                   amd64        library for reading DVDs
ii  libdw1t64:amd64                     0.191-1                     amd64        library that provides access to the DWARF debug information
ii  libebackend-1.2-11t64:amd64         3.50.3-2.2                  amd64        Utility library for evolution data servers
ii  libebook-1.2-21t64:amd64            3.50.3-2.2                  amd64        Client library for evolution address books
ii  libebook-contacts-1.2-4t64:amd64    3.50.3-2.2                  amd64        Client library for evolution contacts books
ii  libecal-2.0-2t64:amd64              3.50.3-2.2                  amd64        Client library for evolution calendars
ii  libedata-book-1.2-27t64:amd64       3.50.3-2.2                  amd64        Backend library for evolution address books
ii  libedata-cal-2.0-2t64:amd64         3.50.3-2.2                  amd64        Backend library for evolution calendars
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `t64` suffix means the software in question is modified to use 64-bit `time_t`, so it will be ready for January 19, 2038, when the 32-bit version of `time_t` will overflow ([the Y2K38 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)).

More details on LWN: 
[Debian looks forward to 2038](https://lwn.net/Articles/938149/)

Comment: More precisely, it means that switching to 64-bit `time_t` on 32-bit platforms changed the library’s ABI, or that the library’s readiness couldn’t be determined with certainty using automated checks. It’s ultimately a distribution implementation detail, end-users shouldn’t worry about it. The rename should also not be used as a readiness check — by that I mean that a library which hasn’t been renamed is fine (once the dust has settled).

Comment: amd64 packages should already use 64-bit `time_t` from the start, why do they created these? It should be applied to 32-bit only